# Is it safe to use non-cash payment in Amsterdam red light district?

Tags: payment-cards, netherlands

Some houses in Amsterdam red light district offer the possibility to pay not only with cash but also with cards.

However, is it safe to use non-cash payment in such location?

The safety I am concerned is about the card data being misused/stolen.

Comment: What do you mean "safe"? Safe from card skimmers? Safe from muggers? Safe from your wife finding out?

Comment: Why not take a pre-loaded credit card as a one off method? That way you won't be tempted to overspend and if the card gets scimmed or stolen your losses are limited. Also, you won't accidentally charge things to your corporate credit card or have questionable expenses to explain when personal credit card statement comes in if you've a significant other half.

Answer (score 3):

Being Dutch and being familiar with the city of Amsterdam I might be able to answer your question:
Not only some, but almost all houses (everywhere) in Amsterdam and the rest of the Netherlands offer non-cash payment possibilities as cash is slowly disappearing from the Dutch payment system. Having said that, the Red-light district is one of the most controlled areas in Amsterdam so no particular reason to be worried regarding that.
Not walking around with cash money is anyhow much safer in any big city...
Have a nice time in the Netherlands.
Bouke